# launch terminal applications, the aircrack tools, from the menu with desktop files

Tags: command-line, unity

I am attempting to launch a terminal program from the menu.  For example; "airmon-ng", I cannot launch from a desktop entry or find the correct syntax for the Exec. Below is an example of the desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Name=airmon-ng
    Exec=gnome-terminal -e '/usr/sbin/airmon-ng'
    Terminal=true
    Comment=Airmon-ng is used to manage wireless card modes and to kill unnecessary processes while using aircrack-ng. To sniff a wireless connection, you need to change your wireless card from managed mode to monitor mode and airmon-ng is used for that purpose.
    Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;intrusion detection system;IDS;wireless;network;security;detector; monitor;sniffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e '/usr/sbin/airmon-ng'
```

Use:

```
Exec=/usr/sbin/airmon-ng
```

and let your `Terminal=true` handle providing a terminal.

`airmon-ng` is the wrong program for this, read `man airmon-ng aircrack-ng`. `airmon-ng` simply reports the WiFi interfaces and exits, then the terminal closes. You seem to have been expecting a long running program.

Comment: I get the same results with `Exec=/usr/sbin/airmon-ng` and `Terminal=true` the terminal window opens, I see some text for a second, then the window closes.It's an instant flash, `ps aux | grep airmon-ng` is not running.

Comment: `airmon-ng` is the wrong program for this, read `man airmon-ng aircrack-ng`.`airmon-ng`  simply reports the WiFi interfaces and exits, then the terminal closes. You seem to have been expecting a long running program.

Comment: No, I just expect it to open with the default output.